# Fancybox simple href troubles

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, fancybox

O,

I have a really basic problem I am having trouble with. I am running a fancybox popup at the beginning of my page, that shows an image. I can not make this image link to a zip file because Ive already used the href attribute, but it wont let me change the code to use

```
<!-- FANCYBOX POPUP -->
<a class="popupLink" href="http://peoplelikeusmusic.com/images/assets/popupart.jpg"></a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want both trigger a popup and start a zip file download with a single click on link?

Comment: correct, you can see its current state at http://peoplelikeusmusic.com/

Comment: any one that can help?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to use `type:"iframe"` to open images.

Second, if you are using an HTML5 `DOCTYPE` (you are), then you can use `data-*` attributes to pass additional information to fancybox so it can execute additional actions within a callback.

So your *html* can contain a link to an *image* (`href` attribute) and a link to a *zip* file within a `data-*` attribute like :

```
<a class="popupLink" data-zip="http://mysite.com/pathToZip/file.zip" href="http://peoplelikeusmusic.com/images/assets/popupart.jpg"></a>
```

Then use the `afterShow` fancybox callback to load the *zip* file via `window.location.href` like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".popupLink").fancybox({
        padding: 3,
        afterShow: function () {
            window.location.href = $(this.element).data("zip");
        }
    });
    setTimeout('$(".popupLink").trigger("click")', 100);
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HrdSq/)**